# Having a problem with tkinter button in python

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I'm using tkinter to create a window with  a button, the button's command is to destroy the window and create a similar new one on click, but the moment you run  the program it automatically executes the button command which leads to a spam of windows creation and destruction

```
from  tkinter import *
import random
import tkinter as tk
j=0
def func(j):
    f=Tk()
    f.title("game")
    f.geometry("400x350")
    f["bg"]="black"

    #message
    Label(f,bg="black",fg="white",height=2,width=20,text="  ").pack()
    Label(f,bg="black",fg="white",height=3,width=20,text="click continue to proceed\n to main menu",font=("Arial",13)).pack()

    #frame
    global d
    d=Frame(f,bg="white",bd=1)
    d.pack(fill="both",expand=True,side="bottom")
    print(d.__format__)

    #cancel button 
    def canccel():
        f.destroy()
    c=Canvas(d,bg="white")
    b1=Button(c,bg="white",text="cancel",command=canccel)
    b1.pack()
    c.pack(padx=90, pady=22,side=tk.LEFT)

    #play button 
    if j==0: 
        k=Canvas(d,bg="white") 
        b2=Button(k,bg="red",text="continue!",command= [print("hehe"),func(-1)])
        b2.pack()
        k.pack(padx=15,pady=0,side=LEFT)
    else:
        j=random.randrange(0,400)
        i=random.randrange(0,300)
        k=Canvas(d,bg="white") 
        b2=Button(k,bg="white",text="continue!",command= [print("hehe"),func(j)])
        b2.pack()
        k.pack(padx=i,pady=j,side=LEFT)
    f.mainloop()
func(j)
```

Comment: I don't really understand your code but I think the mistake is you pass `j` into your func, and also do `if j == 0:` which is always true as j = 0, you dont change the value of j so the if thing kinda just repeats

Comment: the j is to make sure that the first time the window is just created but it isn't supposed to loop until i  click the button at least once, but without clicking it, it loops which kind of destroys the hole concept, btw if you know how to delete a button from a window i would be glad to hear it or maybe a canvas.

Comment: Ya I know how to delete buttons and all. Looking from your instructions it says you want to destroy and create so here is it, `f.destroy()` and to create you could just make another program and then import it so `import newpage`, if you want it do all in the same windows which i think is better here is it, `for widget in f.winfo_children():` `if widget.winfo_class() == 'Button':` `widget.destroy()` if you want to destroy all the widgets, `for widget in f.winfo_children()` 'widget.destroy()'

Comment: thank you  that was really helpful